# How to make executables made with GNAT smaller?

Tags: ada, gnat

So I've been playing with Ada for some time, it's an awesome language, but I can't figure out how to make executables smaller (I'm using GNAT 5.3 on windows). Currently, file size of hello world is about 800 kb. When i strip debugging info it becomes ~222 kb. Any ideas how to make it smaller?

Comment: The User's Guide has a section on reducing executable size. It used to be about *gnatelim*, but the ways may have changed recently. Have you tried these suggestions, e.g. likely option `-Os`?

Comment: @B98 Yeah, I've read it. Gnatelim doesn't seem to work on windows, at least mingw-w64  doesn't have gnatelim. I've tried '-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,–gc-sections', but it doesn't help at all. '-Os' doesn't help ether.

Answer (score 7):

`Ada.Text_IO` is featureful. If you don’t need all its capabilities, try `GNAT.IO`; on Mac OS X (FSF GCC 5.1), the unstripped executable went down from 360816 bytes to 166356, stripped from 192200 to 83540.

Another thing: for some reason, GNAT doesn’t use shared libraries (DLLs) unless you tell it to. Forcing dynamic linking (`gnatmake -O2 hello -bargs -shared`) reduced the `Ada.Text_IO` version to 17520 bytes (14304 stripped), and the `GNAT.IO` version to 13976 bytes (11888 stripped).

Comment: For Darwin targets, also consider `-largs -dead_strip`.

Comment: Consider `gnatmake file.adb -largs -s`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is very meaningful to get a minimum size hello world program in Ada.

Ada's run time does have a bigger payload than C's.

Here is a discussion on it:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ada/1zvvW0Mw5Bw

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in making the "Hello World" executable smaller, you could import `write()` and use that instead of `Ada.Text_IO`.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Standard Hello World on GNU/Hurd with its setup of gnatmake is around 16kB. Stripped around 8.5kB. No fancy tricks but probably gnat.adc with restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

In the days when size was an issue, I occasionally  used UPX. I believe it's still around.